# Different home page for internal vs external users?

Tags: sharepoint-online

On my modern communications site I noticed internal users have a different home page experience than external guests. The home page has been modified quite a bit, and internal users see this. External guests see the home page as it was unaltered ootb. Not sure if this is intentional or a glotch.

This got me thinking; you should be able to define a different home page depending on user role. But, I can’t find any reference to this if it is indeed a thing. If anyone knows about this I would be grateful for a comment pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Nevermind, I hadn't published the page. Still, will be very happy when Audience functionality creeps back into these wonderfully functional modern pages (pfft)... Different pages for different groups would be awesome.